# Constructing semisimple Lie algebras of dimension $n$

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals, direct-sum, semisimple-lie-algebras

Suppose we want to construct a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ of dimension $n$.

We know that if we can write $L = L_1 \oplus L_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus L_s$ as a direct sum of simple ideals, then $L$ must be semisimple.

I am not quite sure of what simple ideals we could use here to get a Lie algebra for a given dimension, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It is easy to see that there is a complex semisimple Lie algebra in dimension $3,6$ and any $n\ge 8$, but not in dimension $1,2,4,5,7$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686562/there-are-no-semisimple-lie-algebras-of-dimension-4-5-or-7) for example. This follows easily from the dimension formulas of the complex simple Lie algebras.

Comment: I don't fully understand that post unfortunately, is there a way we could construct such a semisimple Lie algebra, let's say of dimension 6 then, as you state this is possible, using a direct sum of simple ideals?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We can do with only direct sums of $A_1$ and $A_2$ to obtain all dimensions $n\ge 13$, see my answer. This is number theory, i.e., the coin problem. And of course $\dim (A_1\oplus A_1)=6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\dim(A_1)=\dim \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)=3$ and $\dim(A_2)=\dim \mathfrak{sl}_3(\Bbb C)=8$. By the Frobenius [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) we know that we can obtain every integer $n\ge 3\cdot 8-3-8=13$ as a linear combination $3x+8y=n$, i.e., direct sums of $A_1$ and $A_2$ yield a semisimple Lie algebra of every dimension $n\ge 13$. For dimensions less than $13$ we can check by hand  that only $n=1,2,4,5,7$ cannot arise.